# How to make responsive image gallery with different-sized images while keeping pictures undistorted?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

DEMO of the problem I am trying to solve: https://www.bootply.com/GcLnOddfEZ

So suppose my images are sized differently and I want to make them appear the same size without distorting original pictures (well at least not too much) while also keeping them all responsive. How should I go about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want : [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/r5ma0puw/1/)

```
.img-cont {
    height: 300px;
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%!;
    max-height: 100%!;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```